# not able to access port(11444 & 5072 ) externally(using Ubuntu on Google compute Engine)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, ubuntu-12.04, google-compute-engine

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address       State  PID

tcp        0      0 ip:11080                0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 ip:5070                 0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 ip:5071                 0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 **127.0.0.1:5072**      0.0:*               LISTEN      -                           
tcp        0      0 ip:11443                0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 **127.0.0.1:11444**     0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Not able to access port (11444 & 5072) externally.
Only working on Local Host not remotely. 
We are using Ubuntu on Google Compute Engine.
Firewall rules Added

Comment: Can you show how you had configured the firewall rules?

Comment: Source tag / IP range   0.0.0.0/0    Allowed protocols / ports   tcp:11444

Answer (score 0):

Just checking - have you also configured the firewall?  By default, the ports may be blocked by the firewall. You can configure it to enable ports via either the Developer Console, or with the gcloud command line tool.

Some extra information about firewall's on Google Compute Engine can be found at:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#firewalls

Answer (score 0):

As the `netstat` output shows, your services listening on port `11444` and `5072` are bound to `localhost (127.0.0.1)` which means they only accept connections on the local loop interface. Change the binding IP address on your service configuration to `0.0.0.0`.