# issue to access multiple applications with IP and port on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Cloud. Instance has been created with Ubuntu16.04 image on Compute Engine. Three applications has been installed on it. One is running on nginx on port 80 [say A], second is on 8001[say B] and other one is on 8080 [say C].

I can able to access application A directly when click on external IP [or if give port 80 along with IP]. This application internally access application B on port 8001. Configuration of two applications has been updated for. There is inbound firewall rule for 8001. This application can not be accessible when we try to access with IP and port.
Same case with application C. That application is running on port 8080 in tomcat. Inbound Firewall rule has been created for this port too. This application is not accessible with IP and port. Server.xml for this application is updated to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost [as mentioned [not able to access port(11444 & 5072 ) externally(using Ubuntu on Google compute Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083086/not-able-to-access-port11444-5072-externallyusing-ubuntu-on-google-compute])
I am not sure about the issue. Can anyone help me out?
I searched around but did not find anything for multiple applications. And most of the time example has given for port 80 only.

Comment: Make sure your service A B C listen on 0.0.0.0:<port>, note that <external-ip>:<port> will not work.

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: I believe you @Dagang mean IP range in firewall. It is 0.0.0.0/0.    HTTP error is  (110) Connection timed out when we try to access.

Answer (score 0):

> This application internally access application B on port 8001
>
> Same case with application C.

It sounds like you don't actually want 8001 or 8080 to be accessible; in this case, leave the firewall rules alone (don't permit traffic to them from the outside) and configure them to listen only on localhost (which is not firewalled anyway).

In case you *do* want these to be accessible, then post a screenshot of your firewall configuration and we'll take a look.